# "'knitr' not found" error during package / vignette build

Tags: r, knitr

I'm using knitr to build an R package vignette.  This process worked before R 3.0, but I haven't been able to rebuild the package under R 3.1.1.

When I try `R CMD build` I get an error message:

```
R CMD build Causata
* checking for file ‘Causata/DESCRIPTION’ ... OK
* preparing ‘Causata’:
* checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... OK
* installing the package to build vignettes
* creating vignettes ...

ERROR Error in loadVignetteBuilder(vigns$pkgdir) :
  vignette builder 'knitr' not found Calls: <Anonymous> -> loadVignetteBuilder
In addition:
  Warning message: In tools::buildVignettes(dir = ".", tangle = TRUE) :
  Files named as vignettes but with no recognized vignette engine:
   ‘vignettes/Causata-vignette.rnw’ (Is a VignetteBuilder field missing?)
Execution halted
```

My vignette file has a `VignetteEngine` call -- here are the first three lines:

```
% !Rnw weave = knitr 
%\VignetteEngine{knitr::knitr}
%\VignetteIndexEntry{Model training and export}
```

My package description file includes a `VignetteBuilder` field:

```
VignetteBuilder: knitr
```

I think I'm following the instructions for [Rnw vignettes](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/vignette/), so I'm baffled by the error message I'm seeing.

Incidentally, if I try to build the vignette directly then everything seems to work perfectly.  This command generates the vignette PDF:

```
tools::buildVignettes(dir=".", tangle=TRUE)
```

My trouble seems to be only with `R CMD build`.  Why won't the build work?

Here's my complete package DESCRIPTION file for reference:

```
Package: Causata
Type: Package
Title: Analysis utilities for binary classification and Causata users.  
Version: 5.0-1
Date: 2014-10-09
Author: Justin Hemann, David Barker, Suzanne Weller, Jason McFall
Maintainer: Justin Hemann <justin.hemann@nice.com>
Description: The Causata package provides utilities for 
    extracting data from the Causata application, training regression / classification 
    models, and exporting models as PMML for scoring.
Depends: R (>= 2.15.1)
Imports: XML, R.utils, rjson, RCurl, stringr, yaml, boot, foreach, data.table, glmnet, ggplot2, methods
Suggests: knitr, doMC, testthat, pROC, RODBC, RMySQL
VignetteBuilder: knitr
License: GPL
LazyLoad: yes
URL: www.nice.com
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce it with the current CRAN version v4.2-0. You did not provide the source for v5.0-1, so there is no way for us to verify if it is a problem of your v5.0-1 or something else.

Comment: @Yihui -- I have this same problem on `Windows 7 Professional`, running `R-3.1.2`, `knitr 1.7`. Whenever I try to build a package that uses knitr as an alternative VignetteBuilder, I get the same error message about: `Error in loadVignetteBuilder(vigns$pkgdir) : vignette builder 'knitr' not found [...]`. For instance, I just now tried it with source code for the **knitrBootstrap** package. `devtools::build()` and `devtools::install()` both work, as does `tools::buildVignettes(dir=".", tangle=TRUE)`, but running `R CMD build knitrBootstrap` fails. Any idea what I'm doing wrong, where to report?

Comment: @JoshO'Brien Please give me full instructions to reproduce the problem. I do not know which version of the knitrBootstrap source package to test (CRAN? Github?). Where did you install knitr? What is the output of `R -e ".libPaths();find.package('knitr')"`?

Comment: @Yihui -- Thanks for the hint. I've figured out what's going on, and it seems to me to be a genuine shortcoming of R's alternative vignette building system. To answer your questions, the output of those commands is: `[1] "C:/R/Library" "C:/R/R-current/library"` (from `.libPaths()`) and `"C:/R/Library/knitr"` (from the `find.package()` call). As you'll guess, I have a line in my `Rprofile.site` that prepends `"C:/R/Library/knitr"` to my `.libPaths()`. (The `knitrBootstrap` source is for version 0.9, currently on CRAN, but that seems to be unrelated to the problem).

Comment: @Yihui -- (continued) The problem seems to be that **knitr** and its dependencies are not installed in my `$R_HOME$/library` directory. Installing them there fixes the problem, even when `"C:/R/Library/knitr"` continues to be the "first" **knitr** in my `.libPaths()`. It seems that somewhere along the way during the package building process, R fails to pass on the value of `.libPaths()`, and begins looking for **knitr** in `$R_HOME/library`.

Comment: @Yihui -- (continued) Interestingly, if I get things working by installing **knitr** and friends in `$R_HOME/library` but then remove just the **evaluate** package, I still get the same message about `vignette builder 'knitr' not found [...]` (even though **knitr** itself is in the needed location). Anyway, this behavior seems like an infelicity at best.  How would you recommend I pursue getting it fixed? With a note on `R-devel`, or a bug-report, or a bug-report with a patch? I'd go the latter route, but think I might muck up things worse than someone who's more familiar with that code...

Comment: @JoshO'Brien I posted an answer below, although I'm not sure if it will solve the problem.

Comment: @Yihui Thanks, but that unfortunately doesn't help. (I had tried before, setting `R_LIBS_USR` in `$R_HOME/etc/Renviron.site`, and now I've also tried setting it in a directory-specific `.Renviron`, but to no avail.)

Comment: @JoshO'Brien I really need you to post the content of your Renviron.site (i.e. what you tried exactly). I'm sure you know the pain of guessing and asking questions back and forth. I know it is probably too much work for you, but the ideal way is to install a fresh version of R, then provide every single step of your customization to reproduce the problem. You'd better ask a separate question in this case. As my last blind guess, did you really type `R_LIBS_USR` in Renviron.site? I said `R_LIBS_USER` in the answer below.

Comment: @Yihui Aya. Your `.Renviron` suggestion *does* work. I had typed `R_LIBS_USER="C:/R/Library"` (the correct invocation) in `Rprofile.site`, but screwed up and did `R_LIBS_USR="C:/R/Library"` in the `.Renviron`. Now that I've fixed it, it works. On the plus side, we've learned that `R_LIBS_USER` really does have to go in a `.Renviron`. Like `Rprofile.site`, `Renviron.site` must be ignored by `R CMD build` (or its contents are 'lost to view' by the time they're needed). Thanks for sticking with me on this! (BTW, does this warrant a bug report, or would you like to deal with it some other way?)

Comment: @JoshO'Brien Great. I'm so glad we have found one solution. I rarely use Rprofile.site/Renviron.site since I'm uncomfortable with modifying existing files in base R (next time I reinstall R, they may be overwritten). Normally I use ~/.Rprofile and ~/.Renviron to customize the settings. There is a Note section in `?Startup`, so I'm not sure if this should be considered as a bug.

Comment: @Yihui -- You're right, of course, no bug there. Thanks also for sharing that tip about preferring `~/.Rprofile` & `~/.Renviron` over `Rprofile.site` & `Renviron.site`. I've now adopted the practice myself. Cheers.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien I am having a similar issue, and am trying to solve it using the information in this post.  You say that you got things to work by installing **knitr** in your home library.  How do I do that using Windows 7 R 3.2.3 RStudio 0.99.892?

Comment: Nevermind.  I opened RStudio as Adminstrator as a workaround.

Answer (score 10):

According to the feedback of Josh O'Brien, I guess you might have the same issue as him. If you want to add some custom library paths, I'd recommend you to do it in `~/.Renviron` using the environment variable `R_LIBS_USER`, instead of defining the library paths in `~/.Rprofile` or `Rprofile.site`. The latter seems to be ignored by `R CMD build` and `R CMD check`.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can add `Sys.setenv(R_LIBS_USER="/my/r-package/dir/")` to `~/.Rprofile`.